# How can I get data from Ninja Forms to appear in frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

I just know a little bit about Javascript, I'm not a programmer yet.
I created a `Ninja Forms` to be used in my Wordpress site. When a user fills out the 4 fields of the form and press <kbd>Submit</kbd>, I need those data to appear always in the frontend ( in their 4 specific places I've created in html), and the last one submitted overwrite to the previous one.

Ninja is saving the data in wp_postmeta like this:

```
    **meta_key**   **meta_value**
    _field_12     (the first of the values I want appear in frontend)
    _field_13     (the second one)
    _field_14     (the third one)
    _field_15     (the fourth one)
    _form_id      1 (always the same value)
    _seq_num      3 (increase 1 every time Submit is pressed)
```

How can I do it?
I know is out of my range without PHP knowledge but, can someone give me some trick? Is there a plugin to get it?

Help, please

Answer (score 3):

You have several options:

1. Create a custom Ninja Forms Action. This obviously will require significant amount of programming skills, understanding how Ninja Forms works, etc. Advantage, you could store your data in preferred location and format (e.g. in wp_options table).
2. Hackfix the problem. You can probably do something like this in your template:

.

```
$form_id = 3;
$submissions = Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_id )->get_subs();
if ( is_array( $submissions ) && count( $submissions ) > 0 ) {

    // Get first element of array; latest submission
    $latest_submission = reset( $submissions );

    // Returns array with all submission values
    $all_fields = $latest_submission->get_field_values();
    print_r( $all_fields );

    // To get/display single value
    $single_field = $latest_submission->get_field_value( 'firstname_1531139833971' );
    echo $single_field;
}
```

If you not sure about form ID, check the id listed in shortcode (Ninja Forms -> Dashboard, then shortcode column). E.g. [ninja_form id=3] id=**3** is your form_id.

Easiest way to obtain key for method **get_field_value** is to print_r all submission values and check which one is which one, otherwise, click to edit form, select field to edit, expand administration section and you should see the key for that field.

[image]

Option #1 should be preferred method to address this issues, if you intend to proceed with option #2 make sure to check function Ninja_Forms() exists first, otherwise you will get fatal errors if Ninja Forms is disabled/not loaded/etc.

Comment: This is really helpful as I am trying to do something very similar! However, I am not trying to receive the latest submissions, I am only trying to get the submission from the current iteration of the user submitting the form and then save it to localhost. I am successfully saving the data locally but it is being overridden everytime a different user submits the ninja form. Do you know of a modification to allow me to only get the current user's form submission?

Comment: For some reason `get_field_values()` method seems to take a very long time to return a result